# Laravel 9 - Bootstrap Pagination & Sorting of displayed list

Tags: laravel, sorting, pagination

I have a simple StudentController in Laravel 9 with an index method which allows either BS pagination or sorting - **but not both**. How can I combine the two? How can I get both pagination and a sorted list? **TIA**

```
   // Display student list.
   public function index()
   {
        $students = Student::latest()->paginate(5);
        // $students = Student::orderBy('age', 'ASC')->get();
        return view('students.index',compact('students'));
   }
```

Comment: $students = Student::latest()->orderBy('age', 'ASC')->paginate(5);

Answer (score 0):

this can help

```
$students=Student::latest()->orderBy('age', 'ASC')->paginate(5);
```